# Sencha Touch 2 Logger.js not found

Tags: javascript, ios, extjs

I'm having a problem opening a sencha touch 2 app on the iOS Simulator, the app doesn't finish loading. When I open the app on the google chrome (http://localhost/.../build/package), I see this problem on the console:

```
Uncaught Error: [Ext.Loader] Failed loading 'http://localhost/~vasconcelloslf/touch2-hello-world/build/package/sdk/src/log/Logger.js', please verify that the file exists
```

They told me at the Sencha 2 forum to set `"logger":false` in this file `sencha-touch-2.0.1.1-gpl/command/src/module/generate/App/app.json.tpl` , but I still got the same error. Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your Sencha app root directory, locate the file app.json. 
Almost all the way at the bottom, under "***buildOptions***" you will find

```
"logger": "no"
```

set this field to

```
"logger": false
```

Then try to rebuild your app with Sencha.

Comment: Hey, as I said on the last few lines of my question, I already did that, but I did on the file **app.json.tpl**. When I get home later I will try this in the **app.json** as well and I'll let you know.

Comment: That's it, problem solved. I got mislead in the Sencha Touch 2 forum, where they told me to change a totally different file in a crazy path. Thanks.

Comment: My guess is the template (file which they told you to change) will be used for future apps.

Comment: This is unbelievable!! Why would Sencha release it so that it doesn't work and you need to come to this StackOverFlow page in order to figure out what this issue is!

Comment: I also wonder how this could have happened, but I do remember I didn't have to change this file everytime. Maybe it has something to do with the creation process of the project.

Answer (score 3):

This can also be an AdBlock Plus fault:

Remove the "EasyPrivacy" list, and it works again. It blocks the Logger.js loading.
Or: Add localhost or your development server to the whitelist (a good idea anyways!).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue but changing logger to false alone doesn't helped me.
I could solve the problem by additionally removing `requires : 'Ext.Logger'` from my classes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and i changed it to "false" and rebuild everything from scratch and it worked... xcode 4.4.1 // phonegap 2 // sencha touch 2